# How do I find a list of monsters meeting unusual criteria?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, tools

On the [d20pfsrd site](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/advanced-monster-search) there is an excellent monster search feature that lets you narrow down creatures by terrain, creature type, etc.

However there are limitations to the search. In particular recently I wanted to find a list of all living, huge creatures, CR3–10, long rather than tall, int 1–6.

Is there any way to find a list of such creatures, narrowing them down by properties that are not on the d20pfsrd filter list such as "size huge" and "long not tall"?

Comment: One option is, narrow down the type you want and use the advanced output tab to pull up the stat block of the creatures. Then use ctrl+f to search for Huge. You would then have a list of creatures that were huge and you could narrow them down by the other criteria.

Comment: @Aaron shouldn't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I don't believe it to be complete enough for an answer. It was just a suggestion. It was an alternate until someone came in with a proper answer.

Comment: Don't forget that you can always "re-skin" an existing monster: find something that's close and fudge the rest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This OGL compliant database](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/tools/monster-filter) is arranged in a spreadsheet and already tagged with pretty much all of the reasonable criteria in a variety of ways.  Of your criteria, it is missing tall v.s. long as an explicit quantity, but it has both Size, Space, and Reach so you should be able to emulate that pretty easily.

In order to actually use the thing, however, you're going to need to import it into your spreadsheet program of choice and make yourself a bunch of macros.  Simple macros, but still.  Adding new data tags would certainly be possible, but it would require a great deal of time-consuming work as a value must be entered for every monster.  The group tag isn't very good at the moment, but the rest is pretty solid.

Using your recent search as an example, you'd have the database copy all values meeting the following criteria into an output table:

```
Con != -                        // this means living  
&&  
Int != - && Int<7               // this is your Int requirement  
&&  
Size== "Huge"  && Reach== 10    // this is your Huge(long) requirement  
&&  
CR >=3 && CR<=10                // this is your CR requirement
```

This is in psuedocode since I don't know what software you'd be using/writing for.  Those variable names are probably going to be column references in most programs.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Excel then you can get pretty close without any macros. Excel online has the functionality and it is free - you just need a free Microsoft account with OneDrive. Of course the full version will work too if you have that. Google Drive spreadsheets will also work.

1. Download [the database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1StTeUz_ZBU3pNlW120msjUX34p9cs7kqQbZ2Ym7cSBE/edit?pli=1#gid=125506564).
2. If you're using Excel online or Google docs, upload.
3. Open the file.
4. (Excel) In the main "ribbon" toolbar select "Format as Table". Be sure to check the box that says "My table has headers".
5. Each column header now has a fairly rich set of options to filter by that column, and you can put a filter on every column that you want. Just click the little down arrow and explore. :)

The above makes it easy to select CR, Huge, Int, and living.

Using the above, I got down to 84 monsters. I don't see any way to determine long rather than tall, other than just looking at the individual monsters. E.g. rock troll, dire bear, dire ape, owlbear, etc. are clearly tall.

Comment: Long means reach 10 for Huge creatures, so filtering that should be pretty easy.  I'm impressed you could get double-bounded CR like that, though.

Comment: Oh!  And welcome to the site!  Your answer is definitely valuable and (probably due to SSD's editing) writing in-style enough I didn't even notice you were new.  Nonetheless, take a look at our [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have the time; this site can be kinda hostile to new people.  Hope to see you around again! :)